# Weird 2 body swapping orbit

Tags: orbit

While messing around in *https://dan-ball.jp/en/javagame/planet/*. I came across a pretty stable orbit of 2 bodies around a star

[image: gif]

Orbit yellow:

[image: yellow]

Orbit Blue:

[image: blue]

full album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXTrs.jpg

Is this a know orbit type? if so what is the maximum distance between the inner circular orbit and outer circular orbit?

Comment: Saturn's co-orbital moons Janus and Epimetheus exchange angular momentum every 4 years.

Comment: Horseshoe orbits do exist.   I think that's what you've got there.   They're not very common but they exist.  Earth has a horseshoe satellite.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3753_Cruithne with a more eccentric orbit than Earth but similar period that switches back and forth between shorter than a year and longer than a year, moving back and forth in effect relative to Earth.    Saturn's two moons, mentioned by @MikeG are much closer to circular and more similar in size.  They in effect dance around each other.  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/486/moon-orbits-crossing-each-other

Comment: Stability is relative :-) .  Terra has been orbiting for, what,  3 billion orbits now?  What does your simulation show after maybe a million or 10 cycles?

Comment: That's a cool simulator GUI! I've been creating moons and watching them collide, weee! Here's some fictional background: [Why would Hollywood's Planet X (at earth's L3) be unstable?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/13947/12102) I don't know how mathematically correct the simulator is, and what the masses of the bodies are, but you may have just put each object in an orbit around the other's [Lagrange point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point) L3